# maven-jaxb2-plugin issue with Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, plugins, jaxb

I have newly installed Eclipse Kepler on Mac machine. When I import J2EE project thru maven scripts, it says 
"No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.0:generate in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."

downloaded and placed maven-jaxb2-plugin jar (v 0.8.0) in dropin directory and restarted eclipse with -clean -refresh but that did not help. Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be fixed by upgrading to the latest version of mavjn-jaxb2-plugin.  Open the pom.xml and search for jaxb2-maven-plugin to find the version associated with it.

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
```

At the time of this writing, the latest version is 1.5.  After the jaxb2 version in the pom, import the project as an existing maven project.  Eclipse Kepler seems to be smart enough to download the latest version of jaxb2 automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This approach may help for new project but overhead for existing huge maven script. Is there a way to enable maven-jaxb2-plugin jar (v 0.8.0) plugin in Kepler?

Comment: You could try to find & install an old version of the m2e-jaxb2-connector as an eclipse plugin.  This is what we did before Kepler.
For our moderately large project upgrading jaxb from 1.3 to 1.5 solved the issue with no compilation errors.  It seem like a good idea, so I wasn't motivated to try anything else.